# Connect two devices directly over wifi only with a web page

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, wifip2p

Is it possible to load a web page on a desktop/mobile device and load another on another device on the same network, then connect them **directly**?

I know the webRTC can be a solution for this and I'm using it; since the devices are nearby, I'm looking for something more efficient. I am thinking about this because as you know in many wifi file transfer apps for android (e.g. Airdroid) one end only needs to load a web page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you connect them directly.  You need some way to identify who you want to talk to and to exchange an offer/answer pair; typically via an external service, and then all traffic can be over the local LAN (see https://sharedrop.io/ for an example).  It's possible to do the offer/answer exchange (with some pain) via cut-and-paste between machines, etc as well.

Comment: Hmm, I really have to look into their repository later. definitely interesting though they are also using webRTC at least in some extent. The question is, will this work without the internet after two devices found each other or it is the same as others like [portals](http://portals.io)?